# Escaping whitespace in String variable

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set CHECKSUM_TOOL=fciv.exe
set DESTINATION_DIR=C:\Documents and Settings\Users\Desktop\testfolder
set CHECKSUM=12345
set APP_NAME=price
set VERIFY_FILE=testfile.txt

for /f "tokens=1" %%m in ('call "%CHECKSUM_TOOL%" -md5 
"%DESTINATION_DIR%\!VERIFY_FILE!"') do (
      for /f "tokens=1 delims=/ " %%n in ("%%m") do (
        set CURRENT_CHECKSUM="%%n"
        if not !CURRENT_CHECKSUM!==!CHECKSUM! (
          echo %DATE% %TIME% [ERROR] %~nx0: Checksum of existing file !CURRENT_CHECKSUM! does not match manifest !CHECKSUM! for %APP_NAME%
          REM exit 1
        )
      )
    )
```

So i have the above batch script. The problem is when i print out the value of CURRENT_CHECKSUM the file directory is truncated and instead of echoing

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Users\Desktop\testfolder\testfile.txt
```

I instead get

```
c:\documents
```

output to the fciv call returns

```
bd4e8c3e9b3a880365619e48a779e8e0 c:\documents and settings\Users\desktop\testfolder\testfile.txt
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `delims=` in your first loop? Try also: quoting the variables in set like `set "var=value"`, quoting both values in `if` statement and a space after `==` like `if not "!CURRENT_CHECKSUM!" == "!CHECKSUM!"`, e.t.c. `!VERIFY_FILE!` is not needed, also. Can you please explain what the output of the command parsed in the `for /F` loop will be? I am not familiar with `fciv.exe`

Comment: Huh? And you want to take the path next to the string?

Comment: it returns 2 tokens. first is the checksum. second is the filepath. I grab the file path but it truncates it after the first whitespace it sees (after documents)

Comment: I want the whole "C:\Documents and Settings\Users\Desktop\testfolder\testfile.txt" and not just "c:\documents"

Comment: Please add the output of `fciv.exe` in your question by [edit]ing it! You rissue is not related to escaping, it is the usage of `for /F`: `for /F "tokens=1*" ...` would return two tokens, separated by the first (sequence of) whitespace(s), so the second one may even contain whitespaces on its own...

Comment: Actually, the second token is `c:\documents`. This is not what you are doing in your file!

Answer (score 2):

Actually I cannot reproduce the output you described, because I get the (quoted) checksum of the file when echoing `!CURRENT_CHECKSUM!`, but not the partial file path as you describe.

Anyway, I believe you defined the `for /F` options wrongly; you need something like `tokens=1*`, so you will get two tokens, which are separated by the first (sequence of) whitespace(s), and the second token may even contain whitespaces on its own. By the way, there is no need to use two `for /F` loops, one is enough.

So here is my suggestion of the fixed code:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set "CHECKSUM_TOOL=fciv.exe"
set "DESTINATION_DIR=C:\Documents and Settings\Users\Desktop\testfolder"
set "CHECKSUM=12345"
set "APP_NAME=price"
set "VERIFY_FILE=testfile.txt"

for /F "tokens=1*" %%M in ('
    "%CHECKSUM_TOOL%" -md5 "%DESTINATION_DIR%\%VERIFY_FILE%"
') do if not "%%M"=="%CHECKSUM%" (
    echo !DATE! !TIME! [ERROR] %~nx0: Checksum %%M of existing file %%N does not match manifest %CHECKSUM% for %APP_NAME%
    rem exit /B 1
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

This is what I did:

- one `for /F` loop with the proper options applied;
- used the quoted `set` syntax (the quotes protect special characters but are not part of the values);
- quoted both comparison expressions to avoid problems in case they are empty;
- applied delayed expansion also on `!DATE!` and `!TIME!`;
- removed interim variables and used `for /F` variables immediately;
- replaced (commented out) `exit` by `exit /B` to quit the batch file but not the parent `cmd` instance;
- removed `call` to run `fciv.exe` as it is not a batch file but an executable;

Answer (score 0):

Try setting with `""`:

```
set DESTINATION_DIR="C:\Documents and Settings\Users\Desktop\testfolder"
```

Comment: i am trying to escape the variable here here -> set CURRENT_CHECKSUM="%%n"

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions to this, but I will show you now the most general one, which works if you actually want to remove the first token:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "CHECKSUM_TOOL=fciv.exe"
set "DESTINATION_DIR=C:\Documents and Settings\Users\Desktop\testfolder
set "CHECKSUM=12345"
set "APP_NAME=price"
set "VERIFY_FILE=testfile.txt"

rem Loop to get the first token for substraction later:
for /F "delims=" %%A IN ('call "%CHECKSUM_TOOL%" -md5 "%DESTINATION_DIR%\%VERIFY_FILE%"') do (
    set "output=%%A"
    for /F "tokens=1" %%B IN ("%%A") do (
        set "token_to_substract=%%B"
    )
)
set "expected_output=!output:%token_to_substract% =!"

echo The string you wanted to obtain for a custom reason of yours is: %expected_output%
```

A shorter, but not so general solution, would be:

```bat
@echo off

set "CHECKSUM_TOOL=fciv.exe"
set "DESTINATION_DIR=C:\Documents and Settings\Users\Desktop\testfolder
set "CHECKSUM=12345"
set "APP_NAME=price"
set "VERIFY_FILE=testfile.txt"

for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%A IN ('call "%CHECKSUM_TOOL%" -md5 "%DESTINATION_DIR%\%VERIFY_FILE%"') do (
    set "expected_output=c:%%A"
)
echo The string you wanted to obtain for a custom reason of yours is: %expected_output%
```

It is also possible to replace the last `for /F` loop with the following one and with the same about meaning:

```bat
for /F "tokens=2 delims=\" %%A IN ('call "%CHECKSUM_TOOL%" -md5 "%DESTINATION_DIR%\%VERIFY_FILE%"') do (
    set "expected_output=c:\%%A"
)
echo The string you wanted to obtain for a custom reason of yours is: %expected_output%
```

which does exactly the same (difference with previous is 1 byte **`:)`**).

Comment: @L-Samuels Perhaps [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/1233251) will help you understand why it is not mandatory to leave a comment.